# Get the identified feature

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt4

I use `QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature` to trap the `featureIdentified` signal, so i can get some information from the identified feature and show it in a panel within my plugin.

here is the code, my problem is the connection between the `featureIdentified` signal and my slot is not works:

```
def onFeatureIdentified(self, ff):
    print("feature selected")

def run(self):
    f = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(self.iface.mapCanvas(), self.iface.activeLayer())
    f.featureIdentified.connect(self.onFeatureIdentified)
```

i don't know that's the problem in my code since it doesn't raise any error.

Comment: Do you want to get info from selected features or identified features ?

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup The identified feature as i mention in my question

Comment: you wrote > so i can get some information from the **selected feature** and show it in a panel within my plugin. it's confusing. So you need to get signal from identify feature base on the standard IdentifyTool accessible on Canvas bar button, isn't it ?

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup Yes, what you said is what i want. And sorry for the confusion, i will edit my question.

Comment: problem is you create a new QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature  with a connection. this is work as it's show on followed answer. But you need to catch signal from feature(s) that are identifying. You might to follow this answer to get what you want (sub-classed the existing identify tool and connect to it) : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/130642/53945

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup Thanks, i will take a look at this.

Comment: pueden actualizar el metodo para la version qgis 3.4? Gracias, Eddison [Translated] 
Can you update the method for version qgis 3.4? Thanks, Eddison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple code for connect your [QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapToolIdentifyFeature.html) signal.

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature

def onFeatureIdentified(feature):
    print "feature selected : "+ str(feature.id())

mapTool = None
mc=iface.mapCanvas()
lyr=iface.activeLayer()
mapTool = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(mc)
mapTool.setLayer(lyr)
mc.setMapTool(mapTool)
mapTool.featureIdentified.connect(onFeatureIdentified)
```

And when click in a feature print the id.

[image]

Regards

***Tested with QGIS 2.18.14 on W10***

---

**UPDATE: Add GIF with QGIS 2.18.13**

[image]

Comment: Just to note, to work in the plugin the statements need to be included within the run() function.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, i tested the code above with QGIS 2.18.13 but didn't worked.

Comment: Sorry but this code works perfectly with QGIS 2.18.13

Comment: @FranciscoRaga Hmm, your code create new QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature map tool, i tested it again and it worked, sorry but i want to catch the signal from the actual IdentifyTool which exists in the QGIS toolbar not create new one. Sorry maybe my question is confusing.

Comment: Maybe you question is https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/243502/49538 ?

Comment: @fransisco-raga look on the comment of the question and you will get more detail about the question. its not related to your link (your answer is but not the question)

Answer (score 2):

To stick with your code :

```
def onFeatureIdentified(self, ff):
    print("feature selected")

def run(self):
    mCanvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
    f = QgsMapToolIdentifyFeature(mCanvas, self.iface.activeLayer())
    mCanvas.setMapTool(f)
    f.featureIdentified.connect(self.onFeatureIdentified)
```

Comment: just a note, for to stick the question code need put `mCanvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()`

Comment: Yep right! I miss that

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, i tested the code above also with QGIS 2.18.13 but didn't worked.