# Dynamically selecting t layer features implementing canvasMoveEvent of QgsMapToolIdentify class?

Tags: pyqgis, layers, features

In my QGIS plugin I need to dynamically select features of a layer with the mouse move event.

In [Programatically check for mouse click in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45094) the canvasMoveEvent of the QgsMapTool class is implemented to get x,y coordinates, in [Getting attribute value from vector layer after mouse click in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243502) no "move event" is explored (but I think it's not important thing) but they recommended QgsMapToolIdentify to retrieve information about features/layer.

I tried both of these 2 strategies but neither works fine.

Here is my code:

In the dialog implemetation (in the method connected to a button clicked):

```
    selectTool = CustomSelectTool(self.iface.mapCanvas(), self)
    self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(selectTool)
```

**1) QgsMapTool**

```
class CustomSelectTool(QgsMapTool):   

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.identifier = QgsMapToolIdentify(canvas)
        self.featureId = None

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, ev):
        ### IT WORKS BUT MOUSE TRACKING IS NOT VERY ACCURATE
        indentifiedFeatures = self.identifier.identify(ev.x(), ev.y(), self.identifier.TopDownAll)
        if not indentifiedFeatures[0].mFeature.id() == self.featureId: 
            self.featureId = indentifiedFeatures[0].mFeature.id()
            indentifiedFeatures[0].mLayer.select(self.featureId)
```

the cursor doesn't seem to be very reactive, sometimes it misses some feature.

**2) QgsMapToolIdentify**

```
    class CustomSelectTool(QgsMapToolIdentify):   

        def __init__(self, canvas):
            QgsMapToolIdentify.__init__(self, canvas)
            self.canvas = canvas
            self.featureId = None

        def canvasMoveEvent(self, ev):
            ### NOTHING HAPPEN (IT SEEMS TO BE NEVER CALLED)
            indentifiedFeatures = self.identify(ev.x(), ev.y(), self.identifier.TopDownAll)
            if not indentifiedFeatures[0].mFeature.id() == self.featureId: 
                self.featureId = indentifiedFeatures[0].mFeature.id()
                indentifiedFeatures[0].mLayer.select(self.featureId)
```

in this case nothing happen when I move my mouse on layers in the map. If I put a "print" in the canvasMoveEvent method it doesn't print.

In [Capturing mouse movement on QgsMapCanvas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177668) they said there are another two ways to follow:

3) xyCoordinates event

4) eventFilter

but I'm not so expert in PyQGIS developing and no simple examples are shown.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

with QgsMapToolIdentify tool enabling mouse tracking is needed.

I put this in the method of connected to the button

```
      self.setMouseTracking(True)
```

before

```
      selectTool = CustomSelectTool(self.iface.mapCanvas(), self)
```

It works fine!